# asp.net mvc jquery - display partial page as return result?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

With jQuery, is it possible to call `/ControllerName/GetSomething?parameter=test`, while in `GetSomething` method I have following:

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    filterQuery.OrderBy = Request.QueryString["parameter"];

    var contacts = contactRepository.FindAllContacts(filterQuery).ToList();

    return View("ContactList");
}
```

and then fadeOut current display of ContactList.ascx replacing it with updated one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a PartialViewResult return type:

```
public PartialViewResult Details()
```

Then return a PartialView

```
return PartialView("ContactList");
```

In jQuery, use the load() method to retrieve the results using AJAX and then use some combination of the jQuery fadeIn(), fadeOut(), and fadeTo() methods.

```
$('#result').load('/ControllerName/GetSomething?parameter=test', function() {
  $('#result').fadeOut etc...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `$('selector').load(url)`.

For example:

```
$('#idOfElementContainingPartialView')
    .fadeOut()
    .load(
        '/ControllerName/GetSomething?parameter=test',
        function() { $(this).fadeIn(); }
    );
```